# PHP grouping items in a loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

In a loop, I want to wrap first 5 items in a `li`, and after that every 6 items in a `li`. I'm trying following code, but it is not working properly, it wraps first 5 items in a `li`, and after that it wraps only every sixth item in the li, but 7th - 12th without li.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < 19){
    $i++;
    if($i == 1 ){ echo '<li>'; }
    if (($i > 5) AND ( $i % 6 == 0)){echo "<li>";}
    echo "<div>item " . $i . "</div>"; 
    if( $i == 5 ){ echo '</li>'; }
    if(($i > 5) AND ( $i % 6 == 0)) { echo "</li>"; }
}
if ($i < 5 ) { echo "</li>"; }
if (($i > 5) AND ($i % 6 != 0)) { echo "</li>"; }
```

Comment: If your while() loop starts with $i++ you should try a for() loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo ($i === 1 || $i % 6 === 0) ? "<li>" : null,
        "<div>item {$i}</div>",
        ($i % 6 === 5) ? "</li>" : null;
}
if ($i % 6 !== 0) echo "</li>";
```

I've tried to keep it as simple as possible.

**[Code Example](http://codepad.org/bK89ZCt4)**

Comment: Bit off topic but why one shouldnt use $i++ in while loop? I found on examples on php.org and other tutorial sites using i++, and could not find on google why not use this.

Comment: Your trying to reach $i variable outside for loop on the last line. I think you should move its declaration outside for loop.

Comment: @user, there's no reason why you shouldn't but this is the reason why for loops exist. Makes your code cleaner and more human readable.
@akhilless, the `$i` variable doesn't disappear after the loop.

Please remember what the for loop does. for (initialization; condition; iterator(run after each loop)). In this specific case `$i` should be 20 after exiting the loop, meaning the value that didn't pass the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Here more clean and easy to read solution.

```
$i = 0;
$group = 0;
$group_by = 5;
while ($i < 19){
    $i++;
    if ($group == 0) {//new group start
        echo "<li>";
    }
    echo "<div>item " . $i . "</div>"; 
    $group++;
    if ($group == $group_by) {//end of group
       echo "</li>\n";
       $group = 0;
       $group_by = 6;
    }
}
if ($group != 0) { echo "</li>"; }//end group if it was not closed
```

http://codepad.org/oxJloL03

Answer (score 1):

This is because your condition says `$i % 6 == 0` which means 'every **sixth** item', not 6 items.

To wrap 6 consecutive elements , i.e. from 7 to 12, you should rewrite your condition to `$i <= 12`, so that your code becomes:

```
$i = 0;
for (; $i < 19; $i++) {

    if($i == 1 ){ echo '<li>'; }
    if (($i > 5) AND ( $i <= 12)){echo "<li>";}
    echo "<div>item " . $i . "</div>"; 
    if( $i == 5 ){ echo '</li>'; }
    if(($i > 5) AND ( $i <= 12)) { echo "</li>"; }
}
if ($i < 5 ) { echo "</li>"; }
if (($i > 5) AND ($i <= 12)) { echo "</li>"; }
```

Comment: sorry, made a mistake rewriting his code. Fixed it, thank a lot.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that 19 not the fixed number, it can be anything, so i want to wrap every 6 items in the li (after first 5 items).